# Problems with data visualization

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

When I run the following R code to visualize population density in Illinois, the bottom portion of the map is chopped/cropped from the plot. I don't know why is this happening as I have no trouble with other states.

In addition to this, the entire plots are shifted upward as you can notice. Is this because of unequal longitude and latitude values in the data?

```
 # query map and plot
 library(ggmap)
 library(ggplot2)

 # State of Illinois
 illinois <- get_map(location = "illinois ", 
            source = "stamen", zoom = 7, maptype = "toner")
 il <- ggmap(illinois) + geom_point(data=il_pop, 
        aes(x=INTPTLON, y=INTPTLAT, size=TOTPOP, colour="areaname", alpha=0.1), 
        colour="gold2") + scale_size(range=c(0,10)) 
 il <- il + opts(legend.position="none")
 il
```

[image]
**EDIT**: Here is the output with zoom=6. This is way too zoomed out for me and the location of dots look even worse as I zoom out. Is there way to keep my zoom at 7 and get a rectangular map?

Plus, here is the data I used:

```
    ZCTA3 ZCTA5         AREANAME INTPTLAT  INTPTLON TOTPOP POPPERSQM
1      600 60002          ANTIOCH 42.46617 -88.09995  19350     575.3
2      600 60004 ARLINGTON HEIGHT 42.10843 -87.97724  53118    4721.8
3      600 60005 ARLINGTON HEIGHT 42.06933 -87.98465  28884    4465.5
4      600 60007 ELK GROVE VILLAG 42.00598 -87.99847  35281    2265.9
5      600 60008  ROLLING MEADOWS 42.07506 -88.02509  23406    3267.3
6      600 60010       BARRINGTON 42.16079 -88.15231  40110     565.7
7      600 60012     CRYSTAL LAKE 42.26564 -88.31664  10087     486.3
8      600 60013             CARY 42.21752 -88.24339  24079    1556.7
9      600 60014     CRYSTAL LAKE 42.22662 -88.33067  44525    1998.7
10     600 60015        DEERFIELD 42.16933 -87.86557  27291    2174.9
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post some of the `ili_pop` data using `dput(head(ili_pop))`? Otherwise we can't exactly replicate the problem. I say this because the map itself works otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

At the level of zoom you have requested, that is extent of the map.  It is centered near Peoria (apparently). At `zoom=6`, you get the extent you show. At `zoom=7`, you get a larger geographic area (with less detail, of course). Since you have your population already coded with lat/long, you could use the extent of that (possibly with some padding) to create a lat/long bounding box and use that for the `location` argument to `get_map`.